# Camel SFTP Producer retry for Specific type of errors

Tags: java, apache-camel, jsch, jbossfuse

We had a requirement to retry certain number of times with delay for camel SFTP Producer in case of errors. By using maximumReconnectAttempts along with reconnectDelay, camel attempts to retry for all type of errors but want to retry only for certain type of errors like socketException or connectionexception or jschExceptions and avoid retry for authentication exceptions. Here is the sample code we are using for this. How can we configure to retry only certain type of errors and not all?

```
from("file:///test/dummy/moveFailed=error&antInclude=*.txt&initialDelay=60000").routeId("test")
.log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, " Message sending to Destination")
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("Test${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.CSV"))
.to("sftp://username@host/destinationpassword=password123&reconnectDelay=3000&maximumReconnectAttempts=5")
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"event=${in.header.event} || File successfully transmitted to Destination")
.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to control the behavior per Exception you can do as follow:

```
onException(MyRetryableServiceException.class)
    .useOriginalMessage()
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
    .backOffMultiplier(1.5)
    .maximumRedeliveries(3)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .useExponentialBackOff();
```

When a `MyRetryableServiceException` is thrown the message will be redelivered as per `maximumRedeliveries`.
You can define multiple `onException` or wrap the ones you want to retry in a single Exception...

This has precedence over the default error handler, see [exception-clause](https://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) and [camel error handling](http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html)

Everything else will goes to the default error handled that will retry all kind of exception (**prior camel 2.x, no retry from version >= 2.0**). Unless you override it.

So, one possible solution is to define the `OnException` to skip retry for authentication errors and leave the default error handler to retry the others if you are using camel < 2.0

You can disable the default error handler with `noErrorHandler();` or customize it as well, for example:

```
errorHandler(
    deadLetterChannel("seda:errors")
    .logNewException(true)
    .log("Unable to process ${body}")
    .maximumRedeliveries(1)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .useExponentialBackOff()
);
```